# How to run a sudo command, remotely, trough SSH, using an IdentityFile?

Tags: linux, git, shell, command-line, githooks

I'm trying to trigger an executable file '**post-receive**', after pushing some changes to a **git repo** on a **remote machine**. Within this file are some commands that **require elevated privileges**, such as:

```
sudo -S rm -f $HOME/.build
sudo -S rm -f $HOME/Packages
```

I've **added a remote** to my local repo:

```
git remote add live ssh://dev@ip/home/dev/app/.git
```

So I can **push changes** to my remote repo, like this:

```
git push live master
```

The '**post-receive**' file executes, whenever I push.

**However**, a password is requested for sudo commands within the '**post-receive**' file.

```
remote: [sudo] password for dev: Sorry, try again.
remote: [sudo] password for dev: 
remote: sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
remote: [sudo] password for dev:
```

- An unexpected event, had I not configured my access trough ssh keys and specified my identity file.

Locally I have setup my SSH keys:

```
~/.ssh/id_rsa
~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

**Then**, I've copied the local '**~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub**' file contents into the remote '**~/.ssh/authorized_keys**' file.

I've also setup a '**config**' file, locally, specifying the location of my identity:

```
HostName ip
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

At this point, I'm able to ssh into the remote machine, **without any passwords**, like this:

```
ssh dev@ip
```

This was already expected, however, when pushing changes to my remote repo:

```
git push live master
```

...it asks me for a password when running the remote '**post-receive**' file.

- Why am I asked for this password?
- What step am I not seeing clearly?

**Running**:

- OS X El Capitan locally
- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS remotely

Following the [Digital Ocean Deployment Tutorial](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/PerfectDocs/blob/master/guide/deployment-DigitalOcean.md)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This has nothing to do with GIT or SSH. Linux distributions by default require any user running a `sudo` command, even if they have permissions, to enter the password. This can be overridden (see below).
2. The step to override this :)

Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password#159009) for example.

You need to add a `NOPASSWD` directive in your `sudoers` file for the relevant user. Modified from that answer:

```
dev ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
```

You could replace `ALL` with a specific command for safety.